# Display one row in UICollectionView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to limit a UICollectionView to display a horizontal scrollable list in a single row.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I suggest to elaborate your question, or it will be closed.

Comment: set the scrollDirection property to Vertical. And make the collection view height equal to cell height

Comment: ah.. sorry. set the scrollDirection property to Horizontal :) and try !

Comment: @jpulikkottil Setting scrollDirection property to horizontal does not prevent having multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

I just used something that is working for me:

1. Set the Scroll direction to Horizontal.
2. Set the size of your `Cell`s using `sizeForItemAt indexPath` method.
3. Set a constraint to your `CollectionView` making its height equal to (or a bit greater than) the `Cell`'s height which you specified above.

**The logic behind it:**

When the height of `CollectionView` is equal to the height of it's `item`s and it is set to horizontal scroll, then it can only show them in one `row`. I said "or a bit greater than `cell`'s height" because if you set the height of your `CollectionView` twice bigger than `cell`'s height then it can fit 2 rows of `cell`s and it will show them in 2 rows instead of one.